# Best way to catch "Sequence contains no elements"

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

If `Single` doesn't find the element you're expecting to exist then it throws an `InvalidOperationException`. Only trouble is that other things result in this exception too. For example an EF Code First model being out of date.

I've tried to narrow it down by checking the exception message. However this could change and I'd be none the wiser. Is there a better way of catching this problem?

```
   try
    {
        return DbSet.Single(filter);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException exc)
    {
        if (exc.Message == "Sequence contains no elements")
        {
            throw new UserNotFoundException();
        }

        throw;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.FirstOrDefault()` instead.  Then check to see if the result is null.  If it is, the user wasn't found.

Comment: OK. Kind of defeats the purpose of First doesn't it.

Comment: First and Single have their uses.  When you *know* you have at least one element, and the possibility that you don't is remote, you can use Single.

Comment: does not work when the expected result is of type int, and the default is 0